# Is there any best way to store tweets in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, twitter, field

As you can see from here (https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/home_timeline), one tweet has a lot of informations(fields)so that it isn't easy to store tweet information in MySQL.

If I make this JSON into array, It wouldn't be 1-depth array. For instance, like URL entities in this JSON, It might have lots of URLs in one "entities" field.

Should I store this information as a just string like "urls[{"aa": a, "bb": b}, {"aa": c, "bb": d}]" in one field? or Is there any best way to store?

```
{
    "coordinates": null,
    "favorited": false,
    "created_at": "Fri Jul 16 16:58:46 +0000 2010",
    "truncated": false,
    "entities": {
      "urls": [
        {
          "expanded_url": null,
          "url": "http://www.flickr.com/photos/cindyli/4799054041/",
          "indices": [
            75,
            123
          ]
        }
      ],
      "hashtags": [

      ],
      "user_mentions": [
        {
          "name": "Stephanie",
          "id": 15473839,
          "indices": [
            27,
            39
          ],
          "screen_name": "craftybeans"
        }
      ]
    },
    "text": "got a lovely surprise from @craftybeans. She sent me the best tshirt ever. http://www.flickr.com/photos/cindyli/4799054041/ ::giggles::",
    "annotations": null,
    "contributors": null,
    "id": 18700887835,
    "geo": null,
    "in_reply_to_user_id": null,
    "place": null,
    "in_reply_to_screen_name": null,
    "user": {
      "name": "cindy li",
      "profile_sidebar_border_color": "AD0066",
      "profile_background_tile": false,
      "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "AD0066",
      "created_at": "Wed Nov 29 06:08:08 +0000 2006",
      "profile_image_url": "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/553508996/43082001_N00_normal.jpg",
      "location": "San Francisco, CA",
      "profile_link_color": "FF8500",
      "follow_request_sent": false,
      "url": "http://www.cindyli.com",
      "favourites_count": 465,
      "contributors_enabled": false,
      "utc_offset": -28800,
      "id": 29733,
      "profile_use_background_image": true,
      "profile_text_color": "000000",
      "protected": false,
      "followers_count": 3395,
      "lang": "en",
      "notifications": true,
      "time_zone": "Pacific Time (US & Canada)",
      "verified": false,
      "profile_background_color": "cfe8f6",
      "geo_enabled": true,
      "description": "Just me, Cindy Li.Giving cute substance since 1997.\r\nMarried to @themattharris.\r\nProduct designer for Yahoo! ",
      "friends_count": 542,
      "statuses_count": 4847,
      "profile_background_image_url": "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_background_images/3368753/twitter_flowerbig.gif",
      "following": true,
      "screen_name": "cindyli"
    },
    "source": "web",
    "in_reply_to_status_id": null
},
```

Comment: There are only 9 fields. Where is the problem storing them just like that in a db as columns?

Comment: @DainisAbols Actually, I couldn't understand what you mean. How this can be only 9 fields? What I thought is so many fields...

Comment: It depends how much of that information you want to store in your db. You should store only the basic *tweet* information. You don't want to store ALL of the twitters data.

Comment: @DainisAbols Unfortunately, I'd like to store datas as much as possible.

Comment: MongoDB could be more suited for what you are seeking or generally a document-oriented DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store it in columns. Then you can place indexes on things that you want to find quickly - not the mention just being able to search through it all. Searching for something specific in the format you suggest would be a nightmare.

If you want to keep using bits from it, write an object that will handle the database aspect of it, or at the very least a function that will pop them in or get them out. It might seem more work now, but in the long run it will save you *much* more effort later on.

Edit: Yes, I would keep each bit of data in a column of it's own. Having said that, you might not need to store *every single* bit of info. If you don't want to keep info on "user Mentions" for example, just skip it totally.

Edit 2L to put this into perspective, lets say you want to do a search for "Bob". If you have a column structure like this:

```
+------+-----------+-----------+-----+
| user | favorited | truncated | url |
+------+-----------+-----------+-----+
| Bob  | true      | false     | ... |
| Sue  | true      | true      | ... |
| Tom  | true      | false     | ... |
+------+-----------+-----------+-----+
```

You can just write a dead simple query.

vs something like this:

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| tweetData                                                    |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| user:Bob;favorited:true;truncated:false;url:www.example.com  |
| user:Sue;favorited:true;truncated:true;url:www.example2.com  |
| user:Tom;favorited:true;truncated:false;url:www.example2.com |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Imagine trying to find how many times Bob was favorited. You would have to extract the entire row each time, do some manipulation/regex/trickery to get the field, then tally it up manually.

Comment: In "entities", It has several datas like "url", "hashtags", "user_mentions", etc. In this case, should I make this keys as a column respectively like url column, hashtag column, user_mention column?

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation! I think I should find a necessary informations to store in column.

Comment: Really thank you for the kindly answer! I have to make a searchable column(which should be column) and the column can be access from searched result(which could be raw JSON string).

Answer (score 1):

The harsh but real answer is to read up on database design fundamentals. It seems like you're thinking you gotta store this in one table. You'd want to split this up into multiple tables and join them together.